# Add Rows to DataFrame Based On Values in Other Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, yahoo-finance

Suppose I have a dataframe of the form:

```
                   GOOG        TSLA         VTI
2020-02-10  1508.680054  154.255997  169.949997
2020-02-11  1508.790039  154.876007  170.419998
2020-02-12  1518.270020  153.457993  171.490005
2020-02-13  1514.660034  160.800003  171.419998
2020-02-14  1520.739990  160.005997  171.699997
...                 ...         ...         ...
2022-02-10  2772.050049  904.549988  227.350006
2022-02-11  2682.600098  860.000000  222.940002
2022-02-14  2706.000000  875.760010  222.119995
2022-02-15  2728.510010  922.429993  226.070007
2022-02-16  2749.750000  923.390015  226.279999

[511 rows x 3 columns]
```

Which I can obtain using this code:

```
import datetime
from yahoo_fin import stock_info
 
tickers = ['GOOG', 'TSLA', "VTI"]
 
ongoing = ''
 
for ii, ticker in enumerate(reversed(tickers)):
  print(ticker)
  result = stock_info.get_data(ticker, start_date = "02/10/2020", end_date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y"))['close']
  if ii == 0:
    ongoing = result.to_frame(name=ticker)
  else:
    ongoing = result.to_frame(name=ticker).join(ongoing)
```

You will notice that the dataframe has no rows on dates that the markets were closed (for example, you can see 2/12/2022 and 2/13/2022 are not included in the dataframe I posted above since these days were weekends. I would like to modify the dataframe so that it contains every day between the two dates specified and uses the next most recent price. So for example, I would like to see:

```
[prior rows]
2022-02-10  2772.050049  904.549988  227.350006
2022-02-11  2682.600098  860.000000  222.940002
2022-02-12  2706.000000  875.760010  222.119995
2022-02-13  2706.000000  875.760010  222.119995
2022-02-14  2706.000000  875.760010  222.119995
2022-02-15  2728.510010  922.429993  226.070007
2022-02-16  2749.750000  923.390015  226.279999
```

in the dataframe if I were to run it on the 16th after market close. If the code is run on a day where the market is closed, such as say last Sunday, Feb 13 2022, I would like to see:

```
[prior rows]
2022-02-10  2772.050049  904.549988  227.350006
2022-02-11  2682.600098  860.000000  222.940002
2022-02-12  2682.600098  860.000000  222.940002
2022-02-13  2682.600098  860.000000  222.940002
```

since at that time Monday data would not have been available yet.

How can I alter the dataframe to achieve both of the above goals?

Answer (score 1):

suppose you already have a DataFrame with date as the index, you could do:

```
df = df.resample('1d').last().fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
```

to resample it to each day. It should use next day's value if the day is missing in the original data.

Comment: This achieves what I want if I use bfill. The last thing would be that I may need to add rows at the end of the dataframe that are just a copy of the previous row except with the date advanced (see the last dataframe example in my post). How would I do that?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 in that case I would suggest doing two fills: `.fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')`. So if last row is missing it will fill with last available row. If it is not missing it will fill with last row.